# How to store string value as PDF file?

Tags: objective-c, pdf, ios5

I have been working on the same task since 2 days, but no result I need your help. Below is the issue,

I am storing the user health details in sqlite3 DB and retrieving back in a string (total 8 values I am appending in one string), then I am trying to save the `appended string as PDF file in document directory` below is my code

```
NSArray *pdf = [NSArray arraywithobject:pdf_val];
//pdf_val is the appended string with 8 values in it.
NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *saveDirectory = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *saveFileName = @"mypdf.pdf";
NSString *finalPath = [saveDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];
[pdfwriteToFile:finalpath atomically:YES];
```

After processing the above code I am trying to load the PDF file in the `UIWebView`, but I am get an `error: failed to load pdf: '%PDF' not found` and sometimes it shows empty `webView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing a PDF to `mypdf.pdf`.  You're writing a binary property list, which contains an array, which contains whatever is in your `pdf_val` variable.

What is in `pdf_val`?  If that is a PDF, then you need to just write it to `mypdf.pdf` directly, without wrapping it in an `NSArray`.  Perhaps `pdf_val` is an `NSData` containing the PDF, in which case you can send it the `writeToFile:atomically:` message.  If it's not an `NSData` containing the PDF, then what is it?

If `pdf_val` is the string containing your eight concatenated values, then you need to learn how to create a PDF.  Creating a PDF is explained in the [*Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now I understand what I am doing. Can u please provide me some sample code or any links so that I can refer instead reading the IOS guide since its very urgent to completed the task. But any way I will look into the doc for future reference.

Comment: Google `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile`.